# How to authenticate with Microsoft Graph API in backend jobs

Tags: laravel, microsoft-graph-api

I have a scenario in which users have a calendar on my Laravel web app. As a feature, I’d like to offer a sync between the website app calendar and their Outlook calendar. Now the plan was to add a button where users can authorize and then I take it from there. (Important is that these users are from different organisations. So I can't just ask for the admin permission once)

Every night I would run a cronjob that syncs events from my end to the Outlook calendar.

The past few hours, I’ve been digging in the docs but I can’t seem to find an ideal situation for me. If I work with refresh tokens, people say I can’t save that in my database because it is unsafe.

Can you guys help me and point me in the right direction? I have already tried with the refresh tokens, which works. But is deemed to be unsafe

Thanks!